# How to join tables and pass to views in entity Framework scaffolding based MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I created few tables in db
I am trying to create a MVC application using entity Framework
I could achieve scaffolding
But, I am unable to join tables and pass to the views.
I need a grid in view using multiple tables and also implement crud operations. I am using controllers.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please do some research into your issue, post the relevant code, and what you have tried to address the issue. Thanks!

Comment: The join tables must be done in the controller and passed into the view. Microsoft has great documentation. Check it out here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started